# How to find the position of an element in a vector

Tags: algorithms, vectors, sorting

Given the vector:
$$v=[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N]$$
where $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $v_j\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a_j\lt a_{j+1}$
and given a number $b$ with $b\in\mathbb{R}$ what is the fastest algorithm to find the position of $b$ inside $v$ such that $a_k\le b\le a_{k+1}$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the meaning of $a$?

Comment: You give a vector $ v= [v_1, v_2, ..., v_N]$ and then talk about "a_j".  Where did that come from?

Comment: Sorry. I corrected the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bisection, also known as [binary search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). It has $\log N$ complexity and I don’t see how to beat that.